# Error while Sdl web 8.5 Installation "SDL Web Does not support this operating system"

Tags: sdl-tridion, installation

I am trying to install it on Windows 10 but i am getting error complaining about OS. In SDL Doc, windows 10 is supported. Any idea why i am getting htis error ?

Answer (score 2):

While Shiva is correct and installing Sites 9 on Windows 10 is not officially supported, it is possible to install it and get it running (for development purposes).

Pankaj Gaur has written a blog detailing the steps he followed.
https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2018/11/13/install-and-setup-sdl-tridion-sites-9-on-windows-10/

The most important step is to open the command line and use the following command:

```
SDLTridionSites9.exe -mode=debug
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the additional information as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install the content manager server on Windows 10, it is NOT supported. See attached [link](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-1E52F7BA-ADFA-4BAB-AD7E-65104EE29B6B#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-974EFAAF-DC86-4541-8025-A9ECE4796424.xml&docid=GUID-A6CBE401-9EB7-4534-9362-4B15B19B290E&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A6CBE401-9EB7-4534-9362-4B15B19B290E). Topology manager also has the same prerequisistes as content manager.

The content manager clients such as CME, Content porter, template builder etc. may be supported with Windows 10.

Now, the error becomes self explanatory!